# How can I grab an int from each line from a text file?

Tags: c++, file-io, int

I have a list of years:

```
1990
1991
1992
1993
1994
1995
1996
1997
1998
1999
2000
```

and i' trying to find out how to grab the year from each line..

I have been reading online, so far I read getline but I guess that won't work since it works with only strings.

what else can I use?

PS. here is my code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("leapin.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()){
        while ( myfile.good() ){
            getline (myfile, line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

      system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please use either the search-functionality or the related-section on the right

Comment: all the numbers are of 4 digits?

Comment: Does every line consist exactly of one number only, or is there other text following the number?

Answer (score 6):

You can use standard stream-IO:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input("filename.txt");
    int buffer;
    while(input >> buffer) {
        // do stuff with the number
    }
}
```

Comment: like people are discussing here with the failures of operation. This will fail wherever it encounters alphanumeric and will not read the file beyond that.

Comment: @abhinav: Numeric is fine. Non-numeric not so much. However, the input was specified to be numeric.

Answer (score 1):

If you're completely sure that the file has lines, read them and then use `strstream`s to parse them.

Comment: Why take something unformatted out of a stream, then put it back into a different stream, and extract it again? Why not use the original stream properly in the first place?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: If the file is only a list of dates fine. But if the file has any more data on each line then it is best to read each line separately and parse that so you protect yourself from errors in the input.

Comment: @LokiAstari: OK, there's method there. Be sure to balance it out with expectations of performance, though.

Comment: @Tomalak: When processing text files using the iostreams performance is rarely going to be my first concern. The bottleneck in your code is not usually in getting the input it is in processing the data. Thus input is usually more about correctness than performance.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Using IOstreams *is* processing the data; quite heavily, in fact.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes I agree IOstreams is very heavy in comparison to other methods. I disagree that it will likely be a bottleneck in anything but the most trivial of program. Get It Correct. Get It Fast. in that order.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Yes, in that order, but whilst getting it correct, get it correct in a sensible manner. Designing sanely isn't a premature optimisation.

Comment: @Tomalak: pulling a line into a stringstream is not insane. Nearly every language you look it will look at has a standard pattern of pulling each line form the file and parsing it separately. This is no different. Its sensible well established and a common pattern.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I didn't say that it's insane, though that's a nice strawman you have going on there! Just pointing out a flaw in the over-generalisation "get it correct, get it fast".

Comment: @Tomalak: OK. `Get it Correct. Get it sensible. Get it fast`. Does not quite have the same ring but works for me.

Comment: @LokiAstari: No; more like "get it correct and sensible; get it fast."

Answer (score -1):

once you get the string, use [strtok]http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/ or any related api followed by isdigit() to check if its not alphanumeric and followed by atoi()
chose the apis available to you.

Comment: ya i mean same. whatever best available to him can be used. programmer is free to implement his own custom implementations too. Its just a way to get through.

Comment: @abhinav: Right, but you just _recommended_ a really bad approach, without qualifying your answer with warnings at all.